# Python: Update columns in a list dependant on the value in another column

Tags: python

Assume I have the following list:

```
list = [["A",0,"C"],["B",1,"C"]]
```

I want to do something that accomplishes the following: Set the values in the 1st column equal to "D" where the value in the 2nd column is equal to 0.

So the list after the update should look like this:

```
list = [["D",0,"C"],["B",1,"C"]]
```

Comment: So could you show what have you done?

Comment: show us your effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming a variable `list` is not recommended, since it will shadow the builtin function [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

If you wish to do this in place, use indices:

```
lst = [["A", 0 ,"C"],["B", 1 ,"C"]]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i][1] == 0:
        lst[i][0] = "D"

print(lst)
# [['D', 0, 'C'], ['B', 1, 'C']]
```

Otherwise, you can rebuild the list with a list *comprehension*:

```
print([["D", y, z] if y == 0 else [x, y ,z] for x, y, z in lst])
# [['D', 0, 'C'], ['B', 1, 'C']]
```

You can also do it this way without unpacking:

```
print([["D"] + sublst[1:] if sublst[1] == 0 else sublst for sublst in lst])
# [['D', 0, 'C'], ['B', 1, 'C']]
```

Theres also nothing stopping you from doing it normally:

```
newlst = []
for sublst in lst:
    if sublst[1] == 0:
        newlst.append(["D"] + sublst[1:])
        continue
    newlst.append(sublst)

print(newlst)
# [['D', 0, 'C'], ['B', 1, 'C']]
```

The list of possibilities goes on(no pun intended).

Also in Python `bool(0)` evaluates to `False`, so you *can* use `not` here instead of explicitly checking `== 0`. You can decide if this is worth using, since empty types and sequences such as `""`, `[]`, `()`, `{}` etc. will also evaluate to `False` when testing for truthiness.